# dynamically choose the columnName from entity

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4

I need get entity column based on parameter.

```
private void foo(string columnName, string value)
{ 
   tlbX t=new tblX();
   t.ID = int.Parse(ddl.SelectedValue);
   t.columnName = value;
}
```

How to dynamically choose the columnName from entity? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved with reflection:

```
typeof(tblX).GetProperties().First(p=>p.Name == columnName).SetValue(t, value);
```

Something like the above should point you in the right direction.